# Not able to join url

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-restcontroller

I use spring boot in a rest architecture. I use jquery to call server url.

```
@PatchMapping(value = "/members/{memberId}/payments/{paymentsId}")
public boolean updatePaymentStatus(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId, @PathVariable("paymentsId") List<Long> paymentsId, @RequestParam("status") StatusEnum status) {

    if (status == StatusEnum.CANCEL) {
        paymentService.cancelPayments(paymentsId);
    } else if (status == StatusEnum.REFUND) {
        paymentService.refundPayments(memberId, paymentsId);
    }
        return true;
}
```

On the client side i try to call this url with this code

```
function paymentStatusAjaxCall(paymentsId, status) {
    debugger;
    var memberId = $('#memberId').val();
    var type = "patch";
    var url = getHostName() + "/members/" + memberId + "/payments/" + paymentsId;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: {"status": status},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + $.cookie('authorization')
        },
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            var deferredPayment = loadMemberPaymentTable(templateMemberPayment, memberId);
            $.when(deferredPayment).then(function () {
                $("[data-localize]").localize("norc", {language: "fr", pathPrefix: "locales"});
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            checkError(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

example of url

http://localhost:8080/members/1/payments/9,1

Server url is never join, on client side i get 404

if i do

http://localhost:8080/members/1/payments/9,1?status=CANCEL

that work

Comment: so what happened to the url? and what went missing in it? try console.log(url) and find out what happen.

Comment: i posted an example of url, maybe is the data who cause issue... with the requestParam on the server side.

Comment: error 404 is a NOT FOUND code... it means its not found in server. Are you sure the URL is NOT malformed?

Comment: i updated... with modification of the url... that work